# Getting better performance with transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions, performance-testing

I am running some simple tests with SQL Server Management Studio v18.5 and SQL Server 12, to test a possible migration to Identity columns or the use of Sequences, because of performance issues on large inserts, when using strategies like `INSERT INTO(...); SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM dbo.Test (...);` and the like.

I am getting better performance with transactions and I don't understand, nor find, the reason why.

When I only select and run what's inside the transaction, there are velocity differences.

Here is the code I am using:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_MIGRATION] (
    [ID] INT NOT NULL,
    [Nome] INT NOT NULL,
    [Pass] INT NOT NULL
);
```

Test for `INSERT INTO(...); SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM dbo.Test (...);`:

```sql
BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @i int = 1;

    WHILE @i < 10000
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1;

        INSERT INTO TEST_MIGRATION (ID, Nome, Pass)
        VALUES ((SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM TEST_MIGRATION), @i, @i + 20);
    END

--COMMIT TRAN
ROLLBACK TRAN
```

The results for this one were:

[With Transaction Rollback]

Result test 1:

00:01:16

Result test 2:

00:02:11

[With Transaction Commit]

Result test 1:

00:02:28

---

The sequence:

```sql
DECLARE @ID INT = (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(ID) + 1, 0) FROM TEST_MIGRATION);

EXEC ('
    CREATE SEQUENCE TEST_MIGRATION_ID_Seq
    START WITH ' + @ID +
    ' INCREMENT BY 1;'
)
;

ALTER TABLE TEST_MIGRATION
ADD CONSTRAINT df_TEST_MIGRATION_ID
DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.TEST_MIGRATION_ID_Seq) FOR ID
;

BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @i int = 1;

    WHILE @i < 10000
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1;

        INSERT INTO TEST_MIGRATION (Nome, Pass)
        VALUES (@i, @i + 20);

    END

COMMIT TRAN
```

The results for this one were:

[With Transaction Rollback]

Result test 1:

00:00:01

Result test 2:

00:00:01

Result test 3:

00:00:02

[With Transaction Commit]

Result test 1:

00:00:01

Result test 2:

00:00:00

[Without Transaction]

Result test 1:

00:00:07

Result test 2:

00:00:08

Result test 3:

00:00:07

---

With the Identity column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_MIGRATION_IDENTITY] (
    [ID] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [Nome] INT NOT NULL,
    [Pass] INT NOT NULL
);

BEGIN TRAN

    DECLARE @i int = 1;

    WHILE @i < 10000
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1;

        INSERT INTO TEST_MIGRATION_IDENTITY(Nome, Pass)
        VALUES (@i, @i + 20);

    END

COMMIT TRAN
```

These were the results for this one:

[With Transaction Rollback]

Result test 1:

00:00:00

Result test 2:

00:00:00

[With Transaction Commit]

Result test 1:

00:00:00

Result test 2:

00:00:00

[Without Transaction]

Result test 1:

00:00:07

Result test 2:

00:00:07

---

TL;DR: I am geting better performance with the use of transaction, opposed to query blocks alone. What is the explanation for this?

Comment: Oh man. First, "ecause of performance issues on large inserts, when using strategies like" is an ANTIPATTERN - I would fire anyone using that outside of ETL. Second, the same is true for simple inserts in a loop. Those are unrealistic tests. Third, your question seems to be overly complicated to the actual question. MINIMAL example is not 3 different ways with 4 measurements each. Focus. And ONE transaction stream is really your use case?

Comment: Hi, that's the way they make things for years, I am just trying to solve that. No, I would have multiple transaction streams, but I am testing on one for now. What would be a better way of testing this?

Comment: That `WHILE` loop is going to be the *real* reason why things are slow; if that is your real implementation. Inserting 1 row at a time is going to be awfully slow. If you're just doing something like the above, use a Tally. Syntax like `INSERT INTO... (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table) + 1` is also a really bad idea. Race conditions can and will happen in real life scenarios. This is like `SEQUENCE` and `IDENTITY` exist.

Comment: What do you mean by "SQL Server 12" - do you mean SQL Server **2012** - or SQL Server **v12** (which is **SQL Server 2014**, actually) ..... please be **precise** in your questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am geting better performance with the use of transaction, opposed to query blocks alone

Without a transaction SQL Server must flush the log file after every INSERT.  This is a physical IO and your session waits after each INSERT for the log to be hardened to disk.

With a transaction SQL Server doesn't have to flush the log after each INSERT.  Instead the log is written asynchronously in the background, and you only have to wait for the transaction's last log record to be hardened at `commit transaction`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know ☺️